# Superscripting with a wildcard in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to automatically superscript parts of an excel cell.
I have the area of where I want to superscript bounded by carats (^) although the bounds can change if necessary.

For example Cell A1 value is `ABC^12.5^  XYZ^3.14^`
I'm trying to select the part of the string between carats and superscript them. I'm finding very little to guide me online so I took a stab at this with the code below

```
With Selection.Find
    .Execute FindText:="^*^", MatchWildCards:=True
    With Selection
        .Font.Superscript = True
    End With
End With
```

However, when I try to compile I get "Runtime error '450': Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment"

Any thoughts are greatly appreciated!

Comment: The arguments for [Range.Find](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-find-method-excel) in Excel are . Find( What , After , LookIn , LookAt , SearchOrder , SearchDirection , MatchCase , MatchByte , SearchFormat )

Comment: Once you've found a cell with the caret, you will need to find their positions in the string and then only put those characters you want in superscript, using something like: `ActiveCell.Characters(Start:=s, Length:=l).Font.Superscript = True`, where `s` is the starting position and `l` is the number of characters you want in superscript